# Как выполнить фильтрацию в запросе, если фильтруемое значение вычисляется в PHP?

Tags: php, sql, база-данных, sql-server

Знаю, вопрос странный, но всё же решил спросить.

Допустим у меня функция на PHP:

```
function calculate(a);
```

Принимает на вход значение `a`, производит некие вычисления и возвращает значение `b`.
Значение `a` поступает из БД, некого столбца таблицы.
И в программе требуется выполнить фильтрацию по значению `b`.

Возможно ли это сделать не переписывая ту самую функцию на SQL и не загружая все строки из таблицы?

Comment: невозможно. Тем более на php. был бы C можно было бы подумать о вызове функции непосредственно из СУБД

Comment: Возможно. Но с дикими извращениями. Написать UDF, которая будет дергать PHP скрипт и парсить возвращенное значение. В общем не стоит так делать

Comment: P.S. А СУБД MS SQL или MySQL?

Comment: СУБД - MS SQL..

Comment: Проще написать эту же функцию на SQL?

Answer (score 0):

Поставьте в условии

```
where b = calculate(a)
```